# facing issue while implementing vue router-link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have installed `vue router` in my project And I want to use `router-link>` to navigate to some pages but it is not working

I have a `navbar` component in which I have two buttons `login` and `signUp`, so when User clicks on login I want router to direct it to login page same as for signUp to register page

**in my `navbar` component I am doing this**

```
    <template>
           <div class="buttons">
            <router-link :to="{name: 'PageRegister'}" class="btn btn-primary">
              <strong>Sign up</strong>
            </router-link>
            <router-link :to="{name: 'PageLogin'}" class="btn btn-secondary">
             <strong>Login</strong>
            </router-link>
          </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

**And doing routing in index.js file wjich is inside `router folder`**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import pageHome from '../pages/PageHome'
import PageMeetupDetail from '../pages/PageMeetupDetail'
import PageLogin from '../pages/PageLogin'
import PageRegister from '../pages/PageRegister'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [{
            path: '/login',
            name: 'PageLogin',
            component: PageLogin
        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            name: 'PageRegister',
            component: PageRegister
        }
    ],
    mode: 'history'
})
export default router
```

**And below is my main.js vue file in side which I am importing `router**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'



new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

here is the [image: Image of my file directory]

I Don't know what I am doing wrong but on click of button nothing is happening

**Please do check my file directory in Image**

Comment: Where is your `<router-view>` component?

Comment: @YomS. I don't have any do I need to have it?

Comment: Yes, it's like a canvas you would be painting on :)

Comment: I don't know much about it what code should I write inside that, can you please help me out with that?

Comment: I think you need to start here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html, it has good documentation.

Comment: @YomS. hey when I type `/login` in URl feild it  opens the login page and same for `register` also, that means routing is working fine I think

Comment: Then you *do* have it (the `router-view`), maybe check out the `App.vue` component or your main component Vue is rendering with. Anyway, do you see anything in the console on links clicked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199714/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-yom-s).